# i am trying to make these 2 top images the same space between them

Tags: html, css

I am one of the developers for this website which i have been assigned on

i have been trying to make spaces between these 2 top images like the 2 bottom images. i have used padding and margin but its not working

https://www.eliquidsnow.co.uk/pages/testing

when i use margin-right: it brings it closer but it dosent do the right space like the bottom 2 images. with padding it makes the images smaller i even tried putting white border line but it messes it up.

Comment: We have no clue what images you are talking about, when asking for help you should attempt to make a sample showing the exact issue you are having. There is a built in html, javascript, css tool  on stackoverflow just for this.

Answer (score 0):

from the inspector it looks like if you apply,  `margin-left: 30px;` to the second `.one-third-column` you can have the same space as at the bottom section